# How to download a versioned AWS S3 bucket as it was at a specific datetime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am currently synchronizing data to AWS S3 for backup purposes (using TrueNAS if that matters). I have bucket versioning enabled with a lifecycle rule set for cleanup so I can theoretically fetch the files as they were at a previous date, as long as its within my retention period.

My question is: how would I go about downloading the whole bucket *as it was at a specific moment in time*? Is there already a tool available that can handle this use-case?

Comment: Conceivably you could do this with S3 Backup and its [point in time recovery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/point-in-time-recovery.html) feature, if S3 Backup had previously been configured on this bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tool such as [s3-pit-restore](https://github.com/angeloc/s3-pit-restore) to restore to a point in time.

Answer (score 0):

When Versioning is enabled on an Amazon S3 bucket, every object can have multiple versions. Each version is effectively a separate object with its own `LastModified` date.

To get "the whole bucket" at a specific point in time, you would need to write code that would:

- Loop through every object in the bucket
- Retrieve all ObjectVersions for each object
- Identify which version was 'current' at your desired point in time
- Download that specific object version